# iOS - Is there a way to inform users when mobile data is disabled for any specific app?

Tags: ios

I know that the internal iOS API informs the user if the mobile data is disabled for an application and that, it can be changed in settings but is there a way to modify this pop up or trigger it to pop up more/less often?

Comment: Your app itself can tell if mobile data is available or not using the Reachability API and notify the user.  Your app would however be subject to the usual background limitations. There's no way you can alter any OS pop up behaviour.

Comment: I understand. The app could only tell if the mobile data is available as a whole on the device not per application using Reachability API. I need to see whether mobile data is restricted as per certain apps. Let's say I disallow mobile data for a whats app like app, but mobile data is set to on for the device, next time I check it through the app via Reachability, it returns Mobile Data on instead of off!